# playframework2 compiler error:"identifier expected but integer literal found"

Tags: playframework-2.0

I want to compile a simple template:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Uh-oh. That wasn't found.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

or

```
@(request: RequestHeader)

@main("Handler Not Found") {

  <h1>Handler Not Found</h1>    
  <p>You requested: @request.path</p>

}
```

but the compiler says:

```
identifier expected but integer literal found.
In .../app/views/errors/404.scala.html:1
```

Since I'm not a scala programmer, and I couldn't find what's wrong with the code.
Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of your problem is template file name. It cannot start with a number because template is compiled into a function.